# How to make my script stay executable on different devices?

Tags: scripting, usb, executable, file-transfer

I’ve made a script that would work on rhel distros and forks. It’s for personal use to automatically download repositories and software that I use. When I make the script executable on the host machine I can right click on the script and choose run as a program. When I copy the script to a flash drive and then copy it from a flash drive to another computer running the same operating system I have to make it executable again to give back the function to right click and run as a program. There are obvious workarounds to still use the script but being able to right click and run as a program is the most streamlined and useful for what my script is doing. So how do I make my script keep that functionality when I transfer it to another pc via usb?

Comment: The "executable" is a flag on a file which has to be supported by file system. Your USB is formatted to FAT (most likely), which does not support such flag. Solution is obvious: format your USB to "ext*" file system - that way, your USB become a native to Linux and will keep "executable" flag. Another way - compress your script (or scripts) into `tar` format - it does preserve file flags. You would have to unpack the `tar`-archive on the new machine before using the scripts, of course. But the files will be in the same states as on the source machine

Comment: Format your flash drive as ext4 instead of FAT or NTFS. Executable flag are natively preserved when copying from disk to disk. However you are copying to a foreign filesystem designed for another operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I copy the script to a flash drive and then copy it from a flash drive to another computer running the same operating system I have to make it executable again to give back the function to right click and run as a program.

Execute permissions are not preserved when you copy files to and from the flash drive because the file system on the drive does not support unix-style permissions.  Most likely, the flash drive is formatted with exFAT or vFAT.

Potential solutions:

- Format the drive with a Linux file system, like Ext2/3/4 or XFS.  There too many to list all of them here.  This is the only viable solution if you want to run the script directly from the USB drive.
- Use a container that supports Linux permissions, like `tar`, to hold the file while it is on the drive.  `zip` also supports Linux permissions to an extent.  `7z` does not.
- Bypass the USB drive by transferring the files over the network, using tools like `scp` and `rsync`.

Answer (score 2):

> then I copy the script to a flash drive and then copy it from a flash drive to another computer running the same operating system

Thumb drive, huh?

It's probably formatted as `vfat`, but... vfat doesn't have permission controls.

If you only sneakernet files between Linux systems, then format it as ext3, then **disable journaling** using the command:

```
# tune2fs ^has_journal /deb/sdX9
```

Comment: What's the rationale for disabling journaling?

Comment: @SteveSummit reduce wear on the cheap flash memory.